# Linear regressions comparing percentiles of two datasets

Tags: r, linear-regression, percentile, kernel-density, julian-date

I am trying to compare two sets of data, one set of data has daily total counts for the number of flies for each Julian date, and the other set of data has individual counts of each fly per Julian date.
They are both separate data sets as they the first set is collected by a radar and the second set by observation. I would like to compare the dates.
As an example they look like this...

```
Radar
|count|julian|
|:---:|:----:|
|67   |274   |
|31   |241   |
|3    |273   |
|2    |253   |
|45   |267   |

observation
|individual|julian|
|:--------:|:----:|
|EB        |218   |
|EC        |232   |
|EC        |156   |
|EB        |245   |
|EB        |268   |
```

I have made kernel density plots, but now would like to compare the correlation between both datasets, to see if the Julian dates correlate. In particular I want to test the correlation for the 5%, 50% and 95% percentiles.
Please can someone advise me the best way to do this?

I have tried running a linear regression between the percentiles like so but this doesn't work. I am new to this type of statistics so am very incorrect  but I am unsure how to do it!

```
radarquantile<- quantile(radardata$julian, probs = c(0.005))
obvsquantile<- quantile(obvs$julian, probs = c(0.005))
lm(radarquantile~obvsquantile)
```

I appreciate any help with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to have a look at quantile regression and the quantreg package.If I understand you correctly, quantreg's key function rq should do what you are looking for: rq(formula = y ~ x, tau = 0.95, data = data).

Comment: `quantile()` returns a vector the same length as `probs`, so in this case you are asking R for a linear model of just one data point against another data point.